# EQUIVALENT OF @FETCH IN CYPHER

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Can anyone help out with populating connected nodes in a single cypher query. I use Neo4j Server and seems batch commands are the way to go. Been working all day trying to figure it out.

```
   START n=node:ErrandLocation('withinDistance:[-2.80, 56.34, 100.00]') WITH n MATCH person-[r:POSTED]->n WITH n, person SET n.owner = person RETURN n ORDER BY n.added DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 10

   Exception is "[Node[184]:org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy] is not a supported property value"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a property to a node?

Probably you want to create a relationship? but you already have the `:POSTED` one?

Or you want to set `n.owner = person.name` ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am wondering how I can do something similar to the SDN @Fetch in cypher. SET may not be what I need but I wanted my results to contain the person object

Comment: I don't know why you do the SET it has nothing to do with @Fetch, fetching is just declaring paths that cypher should match and return.

Comment: I just started learning cypher and SDN. I was hoping SDN will magically get me the person object.

Comment: Although I think in SDN REST @Fetch actually means a new Cypher Query against the database hence my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When you write your own cypher queries use the @QueryResult to retrieve connected nodes. DONT USE THE @Fetch annotation in SDN Rest as path matching will occur serially not in batch. SDN will make extra REST calls in an attempt to serialize the entire object graph when it could be done in a single query.
For example,

```
        public class Person {

            @RelatedTo (type = "MARRIED", direction = BOTH)
            private Person partner;

        }

        @QueryResult
        public class PersonResult {

             @ResultColumn("person")
             private Person person;

             @ResultColumn("partner")
             private Person partner;

        }
```

In your repository then fetch your results

```
        public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository <Person> {
               @Query ("MATCH person-[m:MARRIED]-partner RETURN person, partner)
               List<PersonResult> findAllMarried ();
        }
```

In questions case just return the person to get the objects your cypher query in batch and use a @ResultColumn field or interface method.